# Determine what an installer does on Windows

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, package-management

I'm trying to create a simple package manager for my company to work with on Windows OS ( something like apt or dnf on Linux )

For my architecture I thought about trying to run an installer on the server and generate a config file based on that because I know some installers just add files to the system, some add registry values and so on... So I need it to be as generic as possible.

Is this a good way to accomplish what I need? If so how can I determine what an installer does and if not what is a good practice for such a task?

Comment: Your question is likely a bit too broad and vague to be answered... There are `.msi` packages, there are `.exe` installers and whatnot, you want to support all of those? What do you mean with "generate a config file"? Config file for what?

Comment: As for determining what an installer does, `.msi` packaged can be depacked using `dark.exe` which is part of [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/), and from the resulting file you can see what files are put to where and what is done with the registry, but it will take some studying. There might be commercial products for that, though, but from your question I assume you're looking into some sort of low-cost or free solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know exactly what an installer changes, you will need to monitor every single change. On a server, things constantly change in the background, so what you need is to do this in an environment where the software will run that has nothing else installed.

This can be done by using a Virtual Machine with a very clean windows install. You make a snapshot before installing the program, and a snapshot after installing the program, and then you compare both snapshots. Everything that has changed is likely due to the installer, but any software/driver on the computer can change the system at any time too.

You can make a snapshot, wait 30 minutes and take another snapshot and compare the differences to know if something will alter the systemstate while the computer has not installed the program.

Also, Microsoft has a program called procmon (Process Monitor) which allows to track these changes realtime.

Comment: Process Monitor.... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor